# Width of buttons wont change even if i set them to any kind of dp, but height for some reason works

Tags: java, android, button, layout

I think it might have something to do with `tablelayout`, but there are 2 buttons in the layout and neither one of them I can change the width of, they fill up the screen but one of them is really small, the other takes up about 80% of the screens width. I've tried padding, `layout_width`, `width`, `fill parent` and changing other things but nothing works.
I can freely change the height but the width is uncontrollable, and the handles on the buttons don't resize it either.

this is what it looks like

[http://postimg.org/image/b1f77b44v/](http://s27.postimg.org/9z50orlbl/Cant_Change_Button.png)

```
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/name" 
        android:textColor="@color/field_title"  />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:textColor="@color/field" >

        <requestFocus android:layout_width="match_parent" />

    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblDesc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/description"
        android:textColor="@color/field_title"  />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editDesc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:maxWidth="180dp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textColor="@color/field" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="1" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="500dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblStatus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/status"
                android:textColor="@color/field_title" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/StatusChangeButton"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/ButtonTest"
                android:maxWidth="50dip"
                android:text="@string/change"
                android:textColor="@color/button_text"
                android:width="40dp" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblduedate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/due_date"
                android:textColor="@color/field_title" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:baselineAligned="true" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
                android:layout_width="fill_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/cancel"
                android:textColor="@color/button_text" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSave"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"

                android:text="@string/save"
                android:textColor="@color/button_text" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is the desired result? 2 columns with equal width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **weight** to specify the in ratio the portion of each button would take from the whole table raw width. 
But I am not sure why you choose to use Table. the better approach is to use linear layouts.

```
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:baselineAligned="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="fill_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/cancel"
            android:textColor="@color/button_text" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSave"
            android:layout_width="fill_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/save"
            android:textColor="@color/button_text" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this     instead of tableRow

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:id="@+id/l1" >       
        <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
                    android:layout_width="fill_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/cancel"
                    android:layout_heigh="1"<!---add this-->
                    android:textColor="@color/button_text" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnSave" 
                    android:text="@string/save"
                    android:layout_heigh="1"<!---add this-->
                    android:textColor="@color/button_text" />
         </LinearLayout>
```